# Add non-swipeable Tab to toolbar in android

Tags: android, xml, tabs, toolbar

I am developing an android app. I was able to add toolbar using support library to the app. Now i want to add tabs to the app. But the tab should be non-swipeable. I searched the internet but all the questions and articles were for swipeable tabs.

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarsdfs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ToolbarActivty.Java**

```
public class ToolbarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.toolbar);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarsdfs);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
}
```

***This is what i want to acheive.***
[image]

Comment: did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: Yeah. I added TabLayout under Toolbar in my code and provided fragments for the Tabs in the activity.

Comment: Cool.. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Do you have any other solution for this? @KingofMasses

Comment: which you have followed that's fine. by using a tab host - fragments (or) simple buttons in activity with 3 different fragments.. both will work in your case @Faiyaz

Comment: Okay thanks brother @KingofMasses

Comment: But after adding fragments for the Tabs, toolbar is not hiding while I scroll down. Any suggestion for that? @KingofMasses

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87223/discussion-between-king-of-masses-and-faiyaz).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using swipable tabs try tabs by using custome Tabhoast. but the simplest is adding buttons and checnge the fragment above according to button click.

Comment: Can you redirect me to an article or a sample?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html  please have a look

Comment: https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/

Comment: http://androidcodeblogspot.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-fragment-tab-example-bottom.html

Comment: But i am using Toolbar so cannot extend FragmentActivity

Comment: then try using buttons and change fragments on button click.

Comment: or you can add fragmentTab Hoast in app compact activity right?